# Chaining CSS rules

Tags: css

I have defined some background colors that I'll be using on my site.  So I can easily set the background color of different elements like:

```
.background_highlite{
    background-color: rgb(231, 222, 207); /*Cream in my Coffee*/
}
.background_shadow{
    background-color: rgb(201, 179, 156);  /*Moose Mousse*/
}
```

Now, if I want all `textarea` elements on my page to have Moose Mousse color as their background I want to write another CSS rule that references back to .background_shadow, so I only have to change the rgb values in one place.

Something like:

```
textarea{
    height:50px;
    background-color: background_highlite  /* want to feed forward to keep the rgb in one place */
}
```

Is this possible with CSS?

Comment: short answer: no, not with plain css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People have been frustrated by CSS's simplistic structure, and have created pre-processors to write CSS more conveniently.  Look at [Less](http://lesscss.org/), for example, or [CleverCSS](http://sandbox.pocoo.org/clevercss/).

Comment: Yes, there seem to be a number of these now.  Less and Clever were the two I could re-find with Google! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can assign all the elements the same class, and then set the background color in the class's CSS:

```
<textarea class="background_shadow">blah</textarea>
```

Keep in mind that you can assign a number of classes to any element, so you can use one class just to control the background color, and then use other classes for your other needs:

```
<textarea class="background_shadow another_class something_else">...</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really. http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/inheritance/ lists your main options.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no. CSS does not support variables, or chaining.

however, there is a javascript library that allows that. http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do would be

```
.hilight textbox {
  background: black;
}
textbox {
  color: pink;
}
.background_shadow {
 background: grey;
}
```

Or, of course, you could add the .hilite class to your div.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to work with:

1. Native CSS, which is possible, but not good to maintain.
2. Preprocessor, like [xCSS](http://xcss.antpaw.org/), which can create more cleaner code and provide variables.

For simple projects I assume, native CSS will be good. But in more complicated it`s best to use some sort of processors, like pals talked earlier.

In this method you can always use some human readable rule like:
.blabla {min-height: 20px}, which pre-processor by your own logic transform to CSS, that all of our target browsers can understand, like .blabla {min-height: 20px; height: auto !important; height: 20px;} etc.

Also what I realy like in preprocessors is that you can right code, as here:

- .specialClass extends .basicClass {} // see more at extends
- .selector {
          a {
              display: block;
          }
          strong {
              color: blue;
          }
      } // see more at children
- or what you needed is vars {
  $path = ../img/tmpl1/png;
  $color1 = #FF00FF;
  $border = border-top: 1px solid $color1;
  } // see more at vars